# For any ordinal $\alpha,$ $0+\alpha=\alpha+0=\alpha.$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

- For any ordinal $\alpha,$ $0+\alpha=\alpha+0=\alpha.$

By definition we have

$$0+\alpha=(\emptyset\times\left\{0\right\})\cup(\alpha\times\left\{1\right\})=\alpha.$$

So similarly $\alpha+0=\alpha.$

**Can you check my proof? Thanks...**

Comment: The part that is written seems okay. The omitted part $(\emptyset\times\left\{0\right\})\cup(\alpha\times\left\{1\right\})=\alpha$ is up to the reader to assume if you know how to complete it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this disjoint sum definition (which works for all order types) this would work as an argument; maybe expand it a bit more by noting that $\emptyset \times \{0\}=\emptyset$ so that $\alpha \times \{1\}$ is just an order-isomorphic copy of $\alpha$ etc. and we identify isomorphic order types.

This statement is often used as part of the recursive **definition** of addition for ordinals, in which case it needs no proof.

Comment: Thanks for answer